# Solidity : Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string

Tags: solidity, ether, smart-contract-wallets

I just begun to learn solidity by following a youtube video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ).
This is duplicated question for [Why do I keep getting invalid argument?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114552/why-do-i-keep-getting-invalid-argument), but I can't resolve the problem with the answer on the article.
And I have not enough reputation for post a comment.

Entire code is as below.(and it works fine on the video)

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    
    // This will get initialized to 0!
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    bool favoriteBool;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    
    People[] public people;
    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    // view, pure
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        favoriteNumber + favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{    
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
    
}
```

Other features are working with no errors but the accessing 'people' keeps give me a error

> call to SimpleStorage.people errored: Error encoding arguments:
> Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value" value=""
> code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=bignumber/5.5.0)

kassé suggested on the article([Why do I keep getting invalid argument?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114552/why-do-i-keep-getting-invalid-argument))

> when you deploy put 0 on the people variable and click on it after you
> can add with de addPerson function. Also if you want to add second
> person put 1 to people and after add another one

I tried modify code as below:

```
People[0] public people;
```

and

```
People[1] public people;
```

It gives me below message

```
contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:12:12: TypeError: Array with zero length specified.
```

and

```
contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:23:9: TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after
argument-dependent lookup in struct SimpleStorage.People storage ref[1] storage ref.
```

Please advise me if there is any other suggestion.

Comment: This errors is triggered on JS side. How do you call the `people` getter? Also did you try using a newer Solidity version? Handling structs as return values with older solidity versions resulted in returning tuples, which depends on the js library that you use how well it is supported.

Comment: I'm currently test this code on remix. I just click the variable button on bottom left side after deploying. Also I tried to run this code on solidity 0.8.0 and 0.8.8 and get the same result.

Comment: @Richard It seems like need index number to call 'people' variable since it's array. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: sir. how did you handle this problem? I experienced the same error as you. I copy his codes and still happened again.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt4z8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt4z8.png)

Comment: @Zhiqi Liu, Try input index number when you click the people variable

Answer (score 3):

I'm also learning from fcc haha. Not sure if you still need it but just in case if others also encounter similar problem. I don't think you're supposed to change "People[0] public people;" or "People[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ1wO.png) public people;"

Just leave it as

```
People[] public people;
```

[image]

If I'm not wrong, you're supposed to change the people value here to 0 as it is blank by default. (the code by freecodecamp is correct)

Comment: Changing people value to 0 after deploying the code has helped to resolve the issue. thanks to **@shiokempire**.

Answer (score 1):

Please pass the index value of people as 0,1 etc to retrieve the correspondent value.